# Maven Struts/JSP login logout sample application?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, authentication, struts2

Does anyone have a simple maven sample Struts/JSP application to login/logout and navigate over a couple of pages to share? Thanks.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509606/session-problem-in-struts2-application/5517526#5517526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer on the net/googling, so I created the project myself as following:

1. I created a simple maven web application project from NetBeans.
2. I downloaded the Struts Hello World example from [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27) (see bottom of the page).
3. I copied the code in the code section of my maven project. Ditto for resources.
4. Then, I dragged and dropped the content of the `/StrutsHelloWord/WebContent/` folder in the `/Web Pages` folder of my NetBeans projects.
5. I removed the `index.jsp` page from my project.
6. There is a bug in the `struts.xml` file. The `<action name="login" method="authenticate"...` line should be corrected to `<action name="login" method="execute"...`

Then, the project compiled and ran fine.

This project does not include a logout page, but it is a start.