# How do I access the HttpSession inside a Struts 2 interceptor? Should I?

Tags: java, struts2

I am seeing the concept of Interceptors in Struts2. I have seen the below example from a tutorial on Struts2.

In this example the author uses an interceptor to check the credentials by accessing the `HttpSession` and checks for `USER_KEY` in it.

Is it a bad idea to access to `HttpSession` in the interceptor itself? I guess interceptors are simple servlet filters in Java EE programming.

I feel the best place to get access to `HttpSession` is inside the action class in Struts2.

Please correct me in case I am wrong.

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    private static final String USER_KEY = "user";

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        Map session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
        if (session.get(USER_KEY) == null) {
            addActionError(invocation, "You must be authenticated to access this page");
            return Action.ERROR;
        }

        return invocation.invoke();
    }

    private void addActionError(ActionInvocation invocation, String message) {
        Object action = invocation.getAction();
        if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
            ((ValidationAware) action).addActionError(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509606/session-problem-in-struts2-application/5517526#5517526

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing the `HttpSession` from interceptors is perfectly fine; accessing it in an action is actively discouraged.

Controlling access through an interceptor is a perfect use-case. Access control generally affects large portions of applications. Isolating it in an interceptor keeps the mainline code cleaner. Interceptors are the most appropriate place to interface with servlet spec artifacts like the session.

Actions may access session *attributes* through the [`SessionAware` interface](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html). It exposes only a `Map<String, Object>` of the attributes. This keeps the action decoupled from the servlet specification, making testing easier.

Comment: So you mean to say that keep Session access code ,  inside  Interceptors only ??

Comment: No, I mean access the session wherever you need it, but do it appropriately. Most actions only ever need the session attributes, so implementing [`SessionAware`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) is the most session most actions would ever need. That interface is meaningless in interceptors, so usually `ActionContext` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want access real `HttpSession` inside interceptor, you may acquire it by:

```
HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
```

*P.S. I know, my answer is too late for your question, but it may help to others, hope =)*

Comment: But you *shouldn't*, in almost all circumstances, because this is what `SessionAware` is for. Accessing the session directly breaks isolation and ties your action to the servlet spec.