# How to validate a request to a JSP page in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

A request to an Action can be validated using the Interceptors. Also, Direct request to a JSP page can be avoided using an empty action declaration. It is something like this;

```
<action name="home" >
        <result>home.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I want to validate this calling to the JSP page. As I feel that a simple approach can be adding an Action (`ActionSupport`) with an `Interceptor` which checks the action name( and do some validation using session etc). But I've a doubt that whether it reduces the performance,because that action class doesn't do anything and just execute its `execute()` only(useless task...), and where there should be an *empty Action* .(BUT: as I ve read some docs on Struts2, it is said that even though we don't add an Action calss,the framework itself adds and action class which returns "success" therefore,adding an action class or not ourselves, doesn't affect newly )

Any way, I d like to know what your best approaches are to validate or authorized access to some JSP pages.( number of pages can be many.. not only to one jsp page)

**Added:**
Example:
Lets say that, there are some restricted pages where all users can't have access,for example user's account page can be visited only to logged in users.There can be more such type of pages. If a request comes to a such page,the user has to be validated.Then, if the request comes through a empty/anonymous action (as explained in above code snip -only action name-no real class) how to validate such requests to JSP pages? Should an action class be used for this?

Comment: what you mean by some JSP pages? S2 action are called so as to prepare value stack and make S2 specific data ready to use which include S2 tags and any other S2 specific functionality.  I am not sure what exact validation you want to do wit in your JSP page

Comment: You can do the validation through interceptors and for authorization you can define a custom interceptor. What do you think that causes performance issues?

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi. Thanks for your attention and I explained it more.

Comment: @ Mohana Rao SV, Thanks for your advice. Would you explain more how I can handle it in a Interceptor's `intercept()` ? . I know how to Validate for an action which has a real class, but not a JSP which has no real class. should we add a class definitely for this?

Comment: @AashMaharoon: see my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your attention is to secure some part of your application so as only Authenticated as well authorize use can access that part, than you have two option

1. Use an interceptor based authentication
2. User a security API like Spring -security

Interceptor based authentication is quite easy. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509606/sessions-in-struts2-application/5517526#5517526) is an example how to do this, but such authentication is not recommended for a production based and real life application since its really a very simple case.

if you are looking for a complete authentication system, i suggest you to look at Spring security.Its quite easy and configurable, all you need to tell the underlying spring mechanism which all areas and under secure tag and Spring security will intercept them before your action get called and only successful and authorize action will get called by spring security.

Comment: Thanks. I m not familiar with Spring yet. Any way I took a look at your link(thanks). I have already implemented such a way.Its accepted answer demonstrated using the action class. My question is, should we use such a action class and validate with an Interceptor OR is there any way to do it without a action class  Using an anonymous/empty action name  and using Intercepots ow what ever?

Comment: you need some kind of class for this, and if you need to impliment the way you want, i strongly suggest you to go with Spring-security or Apache Shiro to make life more simpler.IMO its not advisable to do authentication with interceptor.this and all such examples are just a use case showing how and where all interceptors can be used but never recommended for production

Answer (score 1):

//This is for authorization

```
package com.kogent.action;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.FilterHostConfig;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter;

public class SessionController extends StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter {
    protected PrepareOperations prepare;
    protected ExecuteOperations execute;
    protected List<Pattern> excludedPatterns = null;

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    InitOperations init = new InitOperations();
    try {
        FilterHostConfig config = new FilterHostConfig(filterConfig);
        init.initLogging(config);
        Dispatcher dispatcher = init.initDispatcher(config);
        init.initStaticContentLoader(config, dispatcher);

        prepare = new PrepareOperations(filterConfig.getServletContext(),
                dispatcher);
        execute = new ExecuteOperations(filterConfig.getServletContext(),
                dispatcher);
        this.excludedPatterns = init.buildExcludedPatternsList(dispatcher);

        postInit(dispatcher, filterConfig);
    } finally {
        init.cleanup();
    }

}

/**
 * Callback for post initialization
 */
protected void postInit(Dispatcher dispatcher, FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    try {
        prepare.setEncodingAndLocale(request, response);
        prepare.createActionContext(request, response);
        prepare.assignDispatcherToThread();
        if (excludedPatterns != null
                && prepare.isUrlExcluded(request, excludedPatterns)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            request = prepare.wrapRequest(request);
            ActionMapping mapping = prepare.findActionMapping(request,
                    response, true);
            if (mapping == null) {
                boolean handled = execute.executeStaticResourceRequest(
                        request, response);
                if (!handled) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                //here you have to identify the whether the user have access to requested resource or not 
                //allow him if he was access.
                //if(someCondition)
                execute.executeAction(request, response, mapping);
                //else{
                //redirect the user how do you want it to be.
                ActionMapping modfiedActionMapping = new ActionMapping();
                modfiedActionMapping.setName("someActionName");
                modfiedActionMapping.setNamespace("someNameSpace");
                execute.executeAction(request, response, modfiedActionMapping);

            //}

            }
        }
    } finally {
        prepare.cleanupRequest(request);
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    prepare.cleanupDispatcher();
}
```

}

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Point to your customized filter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One thing: what if I did the same using Interceptors and using an action class ? difference ? because the Interceptors do what filters also can.. I am a beginner to S2.

Comment: StrtusPrepareAndExecuteFilter is centralized request processor all the request passes through this filter and of course you can do it in interceptor but in between framework will create some more objects in order to process the request(helping gc()) so it's better decide whether the request has been processed or not in the filter for better performance.