# Struts2 Hibernate Login with User table and group table

Tags: hibernate, struts2

My problem is, i have a table User and Table Group (this table use to authorization for user - it mean when user belong to a group like admin, they can login into admincp and other user belong to group member, they just only read and write and can not login into admincp) each user maybe belong to many groups and each group has been contain many users and they have relationship are many to many

I use hibernate for persistence storage. and struts 2 to handle business logic.

When i want to implement login action from Struts2 how can i get value of group member belong to ? to compare with value i want to know?

Example

I get user from username and password then get group from user class but i dont know how to get value of group user belong to

it mean if user belong to Groupid is 1 and in group table , at column adminpermission is 1, that user can login into admincp, otherwise he can't

my code:

User.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.dejavu.software.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2575677114183358003L;    
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date DOB;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String avatar;
    private Set<Group>  groups = new HashSet<Group>(0);

    @Column(name="dob")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(Date DOB) {
        this.DOB = DOB;
    }
    @Column(name="address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Column(name="city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Column(name="country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    @Column(name="email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="usergroup",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userid")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(
            name="groupid")})
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Set<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
    @Column(name="password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="iduser")
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    @Column(name="username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    @Column(name="avatar")
    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }


}
```

Group.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.dejavu.software.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2722005617166945195L;

    private Long idgroup;
    private String groupname;
    private String adminpermission;
    private String editpermission;
    private String modpermission;

    @Column(name="adminpermission")
    public String getAdminpermission() {
        return adminpermission;
    }

    public void setAdminpermission(String adminpermission) {
        this.adminpermission = adminpermission;
    }
    @Column(name="editpermission")
    public String getEditpermission() {
        return editpermission;
    }

    public void setEditpermission(String editpermission) {
        this.editpermission = editpermission;
    }
    @Column(name="groupname")
    public String getGroupname() {
        return groupname;
    }

    public void setGroupname(String groupname) {
        this.groupname = groupname;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name="idgroup")
    public Long getIdgroup() {
        return idgroup;
    }

    public void setIdgroup(Long idgroup) {
        this.idgroup = idgroup;
    }
    @Column(name="modpermission")
    public String getModpermission() {
        return modpermission;
    }

    public void setModpermission(String modpermission) {
        this.modpermission = modpermission;
    }

}
```

UserDAO

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.dejavu.software.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.dejavu.software.model.User;
import org.dejavu.software.util.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class UserDAO extends HibernateUtil{

    public User addUser(User user){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUser(){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<User> user = null;
        try {
            user = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }

    public User checkUsernamePassword(String username, String password){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = null;
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery("from User where username = :name and password = :password");
            query.setString("username", username);
            query.setString("password", password);
            user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }
}
```

AdminLoginAction

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.dejavu.software.view;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.dejavu.software.dao.UserDAO;
import org.dejavu.software.model.User;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class AdminLoginAction extends ActionSupport{

    private User user;
    private String username,password;
    private String role;
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public AdminLoginAction(){
        userDAO = new UserDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(){

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(){
       if(getUsername().length() == 0){
           addFieldError("username", "Username is required");
       }if(getPassword().length()==0){
           addFieldError("password", getText("Password is required"));
       }              
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


}
```

Other question.  I saw some example about Login, I saw some developers use interceptor, I can't understand why they use it, and what benefit "Interceptor" will give us.

Thank You Very Much!

Edit
Stacktrace

```
Hibernate: select user0_.iduser as iduser3_0_, group2_.idgroup as idgroup4_1_, user0_.dob as dob3_0_, user0_.address as address3_0_, user0_.avatar as avatar3_0_, user0_.city as city3_0_, user0_.country as country3_0_, user0_.email as email3_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.username as username3_0_, group2_.adminpermission as adminper2_4_1_, group2_.editpermission as editperm3_4_1_, group2_.groupname as groupname4_1_, group2_.modpermission as modpermi5_4_1_, groups1_.iduser as iduser0__, groups1_.idgroup as idgroup0__ from User user0_ inner join usergroup groups1_ on user0_.iduser=groups1_.iduser inner join Group group2_ on groups1_.idgroup=group2_.idgroup where user0_.username=?
Oct 28, 2012 12:16:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Oct 28, 2012 12:16:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group group2_ on groups1_.idgroup=group2_.idgroup where user0_.username='admin'' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:811)
    at org.dejavu.software.dao.UserDAO.checkUsernamePassword(UserDAO.java:52)
    at org.dejavu.software.view.AdminLoginAction.execute(AdminLoginAction.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group group2_ on groups1_.idgroup=group2_.idgroup where user0_.username='admin'' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch user's groups with the following query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u INNER JOIN FETCH u.groups WHERE u.username = :name AND u.password = :password
```

Thus, you could access which groups has a user with `user.getGroups()`

As for your second question, I don't really think an Interceptor is required to implement login, but you will need it in order to prohibit access to all your pages when a user is not logged in, so maybe thats what you have seen.

Comment: i know that but i problem is i dont know how to get value from getGroups because it is SET type not Group instance?

Comment: I can't see the problem then. The only thing you have to do is iterate through the groups with `for(Group g : user.getGroups(){...}`. Then if the user belongs to the admin group you should grant him access to admincp and in other case you should grant him access to the normal page.

Comment: thanks for support but my stacktrace output is: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group group2_ on groups1_.groupid=group2_.idgroup where user0_.username='admin'' at line 1" 

I use Lazy Load for Group !

Comment: It only says that?? It is quite weird that it is calling first Group.groupid and later Group.idgroup. Maybe the id name in your database is groupid instead of idgroup??

Comment: in my database id of Group is "idgroup"

Comment: The error says `groups1_.groupid=group2_.idgroup` so it seems that the id name is different (first `groupid` and later `idgroup`)

Comment: it was edited but till get error , pleaes check my stacktrace after edit my post!

Comment: i solved my problem with change name of table Group to Groupmember :D

Answer (score 0):

> Other question. I saw some example about Login, I saw some developers use interceptor, I can't understand why they use it, and what benefit "Interceptor" will give us.

You would want to use an interceptor to enforce logins when invoking actions that expect the user to be logged in. If the user is not logged in and the action requires the user to be logged in, the interceptor will redirect the user to the login page. After a successful login, they can be redirected back to where they came from.

This answer explains a bit of the authentication side of it: [Sessions in struts2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509606/sessions-in-struts2-application/5517526#5517526)